# Mongo - Return information from array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor

Currently I am working on a polling app for the FreeCodeCamp proyect using Meteor and have a small issue.

I am trying to create a helper that goes through a collection of polls and only returns the polls a user hasn't voted on. The users that have voted on a poll are stored in an array defined in this SimpleSchema:

```
voters: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: [],
    minCount: 0,
    autoform: {
        type: "hidden"
    }
}
```

My current helper looks like this:

```
Template.DoPolls.helpers({
    polls: function() {
        var user = Meteor.user()
        return Polls.find({voters: {$not: user}});
    }
});
```

This returns all items in the collection and doesn't seem to be excluding the polls where the user is find in the voters array.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to solve this issue is as follows:

```
Template.DoPolls.helpers({
    polls: function() {
        var user = Meteor.userId()
        return Polls.find({voters: {$ne: user}});
    }
});
```

where $ne look over the voters array and if it finds the userId then doesn't show that poll.

To achieve the opposite (so only polls where the user has voted the helper would be:

```
Template.PollsDone.helpers({
    polls: function() {
        var user = Meteor.userId()
        return Polls.find({voters: {$in:  [ user ] }});
    }
});
```